# Find Item lower or equal to value in list

Tags: python, csv, bisect

I have a sorted csv file with multiple columns and I want to return the value or the index of an item in column 1. This csv file has around 300.000 to 400.000 values so I'm trying to avoid any `min` function since it would propably take to long and I need the value in under a second.

So what I'm doing is adding up the entries of column1 into a list via:

```
with open('example.csv', 'r') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
     for row in reader:
         array.append(int(row[0]))
```

And now comes the tricky part since I couldn't find a suitable function and/or example who was looking for a lower or equal value.
I tried editing this example I found on stackoverflow.com

```
def find_closest(t):
 idx = bisect.bisect_left(array, t) # Find insertion point

# Check which timestamp with idx or idx - 1 is closer
 if idx > 0 and abs(array[idx] - value) > abs(array[idx - 1] - value):
     idx -= 1

 return array[idx]
```

This example is giving out the closest value, lower, equal or greater. But I couldn't manage to change it the way I want to.

As an example with numbers what I'm looking for is:

```
array=[123,123,123,124,125,125,125,128,128,128,128]
value1=124
value2=127
```

So when looking for value1 it should return the `return1=124` or the index.
When the value isn't included like value2 it should return the highest value that is lower than the searched value. `return2=125`even if the higher value, 128, is closer.

I tried using the bisect module but I failed miserably. Any tipps are appreciated.

Greetings

Comment: if column 1 is sorted then binary search (bisection) is your friend, so perhaps expand on "I failed miserably".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming that you have a sorted list:

```
def foo(the_list, value):
    index = bisect.bisect_left(the_list, value)
    return the_list[index] if the_list[index] == value or index == 0 else the_list[index-1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I messed up the return value. Now everything is working.